# I can't fix this seemingly, simple, cast related, postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, types, casting

So, I have this query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM table1 INNER JOIN "some query" 
WHERE "some more query" 
OR (table.smowid NOT LIKE (58)) OR "rest of query"
```

Sorry for the unclear code, the full query is quite big, but the problem is in the `table.smowid NOT LIKE (58)` part.

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer !~~ integer
LINE 11: or ( (table.smowid) NOT LIKE (58))
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I unfortunately, don't know much about casts and types, but why is the DB complaining when it's going from integer to integer? 
I tried CASTING by saying `(CAST (table.smowid) AS INTEGER) NOT LIKE (58)` but that didn't work, I also tried `(table.smowid :: integer) NOT LIKE (58)` but that also didn't work for some reason.

So, what should I do? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should cast them both to text or, better yet, have a `smowis` column with all the `smowi` values as text to save the overhead of casting each time.

Comment: Yup casting as text seems to have fixed the issue, just curious, but what's the difference between ::TEXT and CAST something AS TEXT ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's just syntactical sugar and does the same thing.

Comment: `myval::text`, `text myval` and `cast myval as text` are 100 % equivalent in postgres. The latter is the standard SQL syntax. `myval::text` is my preferred style, because it is easiest to read.

Answer (score 2):

`NOT LIKE` and its equivalent `!~~` are definitely not integer operators. What are you trying to do with a [pattern matching operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) on integers?

There's a way to use it but you first have to cast (or [format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)) the integers to text.

Comment: hmm, I didn't write the code, so I don't understand it all that well, but are you saying that the pattern matching operator (i.e. the LIKE thingy) doesn't work on integers? That's interesting, so would it work if I cast both the table.smowid bit and the pattern as text? 
I am just curious but would this have worked in MySQL? The code was originally written with MySQL in mind.

Comment: Quote (from [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html): "In MySQL, LIKE is permitted on numeric expressions. (This is an extension to the standard SQL LIKE.)". For the rational behind this extension you should ask the MySQL developers.